# No known controllers and their joints in MoveIt! when connecting real robot

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I was setting up MoveIt! for my robot, which uses [ros_canopen](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_canopen?distro=indigo) as its driver. I used moveit_setup_assistant to generate the moveit_config package and follow [this tutorial](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/pr2_tutorials/planning/src/doc/controller_configuration.html) to configure MoveIt! to talk to the real robot.

Rostopic list shows that the **FollowJointTrajectory** action on the server side(robot driver) is ready:

```
/joint_trajectory_controller/command
/joint_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/cancel
/joint_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/feedback
/joint_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/goal
/joint_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/result
/joint_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/status
/joint_trajectory_controller/state
```

My **controller.yaml** for the MoveIt side is

```
controller_list:  
 - name:  joint_trajectory_controller 
   action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
   type: FollowJointTrajectory
   default: true
   joints: 
     - I1_Joint
     - T2_Joint
     - T3_Joint
     - i4_Joint
     - t5_Joint
```

When I clicked the execute button in rviz, errors showed up:

```
[ERROR]: Unable to identify any set of controllers that can actuate the specified joints: [ I1_Joint T2_Joint T3_Joint i4_Joint t5_Joint ]
[ERROR] : Known controllers and their joints:
[ERROR] : Apparently trajectory initialization failed
```

[The moveit_controller_manager.launch](https://github.com/Linkeway/BIRL_modular_robot/blob/master/manipulator5d_moveit_config/launch/manipulator5d_moveit_controller_manager.launch) starts the moveit side for the system.
I use Indigo and Ubuntu14.04.

Any help will be much appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250855/no-known-controllers-and-their-joints-in-moveit!-when-connecting-real-robot./) by [Craig](https://answers.ros.org/users/26391/craig/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2016-12-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You did not follow through with this part of the tutorial: http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/pr2_tutorials/planning/src/doc/controller_configuration.html#create-the-controller-launch-file

Instead of filling in the `Manipulator5d_moveit_controller_manager.launch.xml` as it is stated in the tutorial, you created
your own `manipulator5d_moveit_controller_manager.launch` and copy&pasted launch descriptions from the other files.

The concrete problem because of which move_group can't find your controller is that you load the `controller.yaml` file yourself
and do not put it in the right namespace. move_group expects to find the parameter in `/move_group/controller_list` but your launch file
loads it in `/controller_list`.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2016-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Craig](https://answers.ros.org/users/26391/craig/) on 2016-12-28**:
It works. Thanks! I think the tutorial should make this clear.

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2016-12-28**:
please provide a patch! :)
https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_tutorials/blob/indigo-devel/doc/pr2_tutorials/planning/src/doc/controller_configuration.rst